# Get the value for foreign key - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, code-first

So I have two models:

```
public class User 
{ 
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public Group myGroup {get;set;}  
}

public class Group 
{
    public int id 
    public ICollection<User> Users {get;set;} 
}
```

But when I query the user to get the GroupID - no matter how I try, I always get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I tried getting the userID from the UserStore (

```
User currentUser = usrStore.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name)
```

) and then:

```
Group myGroup = context.Group.Find(currentUser.Group);
```

To get the Group object loaded and use it later (myGroup.Id for example).

Comment: It *does* matter how you try, please show us.

Comment: Added how I am trying now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework, your code is missing a couple of items.

First, add in the foreign key relationship into the `User` class like this:

```
public int GroupId { get; set; }
```

Secondly, change your Group property to be virtual like this:

```
public virtual Group myGroup {get;set;}
```

That should do it, but you should probably also make the `Users` property of the `Group` class virtual too.

Comment: I did both things, still getting the same error. The User group is actually the ASP.Net Identity 2.0, so that might be why. Everything is mapping with the keys in the DB correctly, but for some reason I can't get the value for the GroupID field.

Comment: @Ivan So does your `User` class inherit from `IdentityUser`?

Comment: You probably also need `[Key]` attribute on `id` in the `Group` class.

Comment: It's not in the question?

Comment: My bad, sorry! Also, looks like another install on my server messed up the cookies somehow, and i was trying to pull data for a user from the other app (no idea how it happened). Tried with fixed name values and it works now! Thank you David and Haim for your time!